# Why is the shape select offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js and am having a problem that is similar to the one in the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var grid = 50;

// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: true }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
  });
});
```

When I copy and paste the code exactly I get an issue where the shape selector seems to be on the bottom right of the shape (off the shape).  In this example I can't move the shape when I hover over it.  I can only move when I drag from the bottom right.

This fiddle does not have the same issue on fiddle but when I bring the code onto my machine I have the same issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/

What am I missing??

Thanks

**Update**

It seems specific the computer I am working on.  I was able to install and run on another machine without the issue.  Both are using Xampp, firefox.  The only difference is Win 10 and Win 7 but would that cause the issue??

There is a difference when they load on each computer.

Not working one html looks like this...

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative; -moz-user-select: none;">
<canvas id="canvas" class="lower-canvas" height="450" width="450" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas " style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default;" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Working looks like this

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative; -moz-user-select: none;">
<canvas id="canvas" class="lower-canvas" height="300" width="300" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas " style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default;" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Why is the class going to 450 for the height and width???

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this at all on Mac OSX, Firefox or Chrome. Perhaps it's an extension on the broken computer interfering. Voting to close due to "cannot reproduce".

Comment: I tried it on a number of browers on the not working computer but same results.  Am I able to post a screen shot?  Any suggestions on how I could trouble shoot further?  On all the browsers its expanding that lower canvas size regardless of what I add for the div dimensions.

Comment: could be something related to dpi of the screen. In windows 10 how big are your fonts? 100& oe 150%, 125%?

Comment: Would this be changing the html?  My level is set to 150% (which is what the class is being enlarged to 300 --> 450.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was but upgraded to the latest issue of Fabric JS (1.7.2) and the issue is gone.